# Omniauth: Login with Github (404 access token)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, sinatra, omniauth

I use Omniauth to let users login with Github.

**Step 1.** The user is sent to `/auth/github` and then redirected to github to login.

**Step 2.** The user authenticates itself and Github return this string and a `code` parameter:

```
<# extra=# private_gists=0 public_gists=0 public_repos=0 total_private_repos=0 type="User" url="https://api.github.com/users/XXXXX">> info=#> provider="github" uid=13XXXXX>

params[:code] = CODEXXXXXXXXX
```

**Step 2.** Then, I try to retreive the token by sending a post request to :

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token
```

with parameters: client_id, client_secret and the code received in step 1 but I get 404.

**Question 1:** Are these steps correct or am I missing something ?

**Question 2:** What are the parameters that I need to save in the database to authenticate after successful login (I use a User model).

Comment: Hey, I see you marked it as correctly answered...did you figure it out? I would love to know what was up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using Omniauth, you should just point the user to

```
"/auth/github"
```

and then set a route like this:

```
match '/auth/:provider/callback', :to => 'sessions#create'
match '/auth/failure', :to => 'sessions#failure'
```

Omniauth will handle everything else and you will be returned a hash with all the user information.

Then to get the access token, you have to submit a post request as follows:

```
POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?
client_id=...&
redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/oauth_redirect&
client_secret=...&
code=...
```

I think you are missing the redirect_uri, so GitHub is redirecting by submitting a GET request to https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token, which returns a 404 error.

Comment: Thank you but I already did that, authentication works. The issue is with the 404 reponse and what to save in the database.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do. Can you be a little clearer in your explanation?

Comment: @Jane Nevermind, I understand now. You may be missing the redirect url. On the GitHub site, it says you need

`POST https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?
   client_id=...&
   redirect_uri=http://www.example.com/oauth_redirect&
   client_secret=...&
   code=...`

Comment: Sorry it didn't work :( + the redirect_uri is optional. `http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/`.

Comment: Whoops, well that's all I got. I'd love to see the resolution if there is one.

Comment: Actually, one more thought: have you tried requesting scopes?

Comment: Yes did but doesn't change anything. Thanks you for your time. Let me know if you figure out later.

Comment: It's probably something to do with the way you pass back the client_secret. From what I understand, GitHub returns a 404 page if the authorization is invalid, so that's probably what's happening. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Answer (score 5):

Well, though it's really silly this has happened to me too and the reason was...
I mixed up the `client_id` with the `client_secret` when copy pasting them ;-)

The end result is as described, github responding with 404.
Possible that this was the "problem" behind this issue too ;-)